# How to Confirm if Settings.Default.Save() has written into the user config file

Tags: c#

I want to know if there is any possibility to know whether the `Settings.Default.Save()` method has written to the config file. Due to some issues in the code it could fail to persist. How will I come to know about that?

Is there any callbacks, or Events or return value to know that?
Please help me!!

Comment: Why not fix the `issues in the code` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the method would throw an exception if it failed.

Comment: Why not read the same setting after saving. If you can read then it has saved else .....

Comment: Output Window probably

Comment: Save doesn't write to the application's config file, it writes to the *user's* config file and saves *user settings*. The application's config file can't be modified, which is actually a good thing. Only application settings are supposed to go there, and they should only be modified during installation or by an administrator.

Comment: What is the *actual* question? `Save` typically won't fail from issues in the code, it will fail if there is no disk space etc. What exactly is the error? Did you think that `Save` would modify the `exe.config`?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos-Ya i meant the user config file only.

Comment: And? What is the problem? Do you get an exception? If the problem is that you can't serialize a specific type, *post that code and exception!*. `Save` is *guaranteed* to fail in this case. You don't need any return values or event handlers, the method will throw an exception. The only way to miss this is if you have code to *hide* the exception

Answer (score 3):

Dissambled `ClientSettingsStore` that is invoked when `Settings.Default`Save()` is called:

```
internal void WriteSettings(string sectionName, bool isRoaming, IDictionary newSettings)
{
    if (!ConfigurationManagerInternalFactory.Instance.SupportsUserConfig)
         throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(System.SR.GetString("UserSettingsNotSupported"));
    ...
    if (configSection == null)
         throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(System.SR.GetString("SettingsSaveFailedNoSection"));
    ...
    try
    {
        userConfig.Save();
    }
    catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex)
    {
         throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(System.SR.GetString("SettingsSaveFailed", new object[1]
              {
               (object) ex.Message
              }), (Exception) ex);
    }
}
```

Going deeper in call stack (f.e. `userConfig.Save()`) brings us to class `MgmtConfigurationRecord` class and method `SaveAs` that also throws approperiate exceptions.

As you can see, in case of errors exceptions are thrown.

So:

```
try
{ 
   Settings.Default.Save();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //sth went wrong
}
```

is enough in my opinion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - although you can argue there is no question to answer. I'd bet the OP doesn't realize that `Save()` saves user settings.

Comment: @nopeflow- Thanks for your answer. I asked this question because when I tried to save a custom class type collection as a setting, due to some issues it wasn't persisting. But to find out that i thought if a return value or event handler could be used that will make the job easy.

Comment: @sandy93 then you have a serialization issue and you'll have to *fix it*. Post the type that causes the exception and the full exception message (including the call stack). You *already* know that saving failed because an *exception* is thrown in this case. You don't need a return value or an event handler

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos- I fixed the issue. No exception was thrown that was notified i.e the execution was stopped. So I didn't know